# How to avoid changing ownership of every file in a volume when starting a docker container using docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, minecraft

I am relatively new to docker and docker-compose so as my first project I have been working on making a Minecraft server. I am using an image from marctv with the latest PaperMC server. I am also using dynmap to create a nice map of the world which has created a ton of assets within the volume. Everything is working so far but every time I start my docker compose I get thousands of messages like this:

```
minecraftserver  | ownership of '/data/plugins/dynmap/web/tiles/world/ct/-8_4/-242_150.jpg' retained as dockeruser:dockergroup
minecraftserver  | ownership of '/data/plugins/dynmap/web/tiles/world/ct/-8_4/-248_152.jpg' retained as dockeruser:dockergroup
minecraftserver  | ownership of '/data/plugins/dynmap/web/tiles/world/ct/-8_4/-253_133.jpg' retained as dockeruser:dockergroup
minecraftserver  | ownership of '/data/plugins/dynmap/web/tiles/world/ct/-8_4/-225_141.jpg' retained as dockeruser:dockergroup
minecraftserver  | ownership of '/data/plugins/dynmap/web/tiles/world/ct/-8_4/-227_159.jpg' retained as dockeruser:dockergroup
minecraftserver  | ownership of '/data/plugins/dynmap/web/tiles/world/ct/-8_4/-249_145.jpg' retained as dockeruser:dockergroup
```

My docker compose looks like this:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  minecraft:
    image: "marctv/minecraft-papermc-server:latest"
    #restart: always
    container_name: "minecraftserver"
    environment:
      MEMORYSIZE: "6G"
      PAPERMC_FLAGS: ""
    volumes:
      - "/home/mcserver:/data:rw"
    ports:
      # mcserver
      - "25565:25565"
      # dynmap
      - "25566:25566"
    # The following allow `docker attach minecraft` to work
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

My thought process was that there had to be a permissions issue. I tried setting a user in my docker compose but then I get an error when starting docker

```
minecraftserver  | First start of the docker container, start initialization process.
minecraftserver  | Starting with 9001:9001 (UID:GID)
minecraftserver  | addgroup: Only root may add a user or group to the system.
minecraftserver exited with code 1
```

Any guidance on this would be helpful. I tried to be detailed but can add any information needed.

Comment: The messages you're showing aren't default Docker messages; neither Docker nor Compose on their own changes the ownership of mounted files.  Is this being done by an entrypoint script in the image?  Do you have enough application source code to fully demonstrate the image?

Comment: Yes as I was looking more into it, I found an entrypoint script in the github of the image [link] https://github.com/mtoensing/Docker-Minecraft-PaperMC-Server/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh

Answer (score 0):

This is easily fixable by creating a user with the same UID as yours on the host machine:

- On your host machine, use the `id` command to find your UID, then create a user from your Dockerfile using useradd or adduser (depending on your distribution).
- Use the `USER` directive at the end of your Dockerfile to tell Docker to use this user when running the container
- Rebuild your images

Here is an example:

```
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash my_user
RUN usermod -u 1000 my_user

USER my_user
```

You can also use the `user` entry from a `docker-compose.yml` file like this:

```yaml
version: '3.6'

services:
  my-service:
    image: node:18
    user: "1000:1000" # (UID:GID)
```